# SSHJ and multiple threads

Tags: java, sshj

I have a question about SSHJ and multiple threads.  I have a class that uses SSHJ to execute commands on a remote server using the SSHJ SSHExec class and it is an extension of Threads.  I am doing this because some of the remote commands can take a while to run, and I want to run them in parallel since they do not effect each other.

So my in my setup I have class_A that can start multiple version of class_B, which is the program that executes the SSH commands.  When I configure class_A to only start one instance of class_B everything works fine.  But when I configure class_A to start more then one instance of class_B it fails with the following error.

```
Aug 2, 2012 12:08:44 PM backup.SSHExec run
SEVERE: null
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Unexpected: SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException$1.chain(TransportException.java:33)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException$1.chain(TransportException.java:27)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise.deliverError(Promise.java:95)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.Event.deliverError(Event.java:72)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.ErrorDeliveryUtil.alertEvents(ErrorDeliveryUtil.java:34)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.die(TransportImpl.java:576)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:79)
Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.common.SSHException: [PROTOCOL_ERROR] Unexpected: SSH_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED
    at net.schmizz.sshj.AbstractService.notifyUnimplemented(AbstractService.java:66)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.gotUnimplemented(TransportImpl.java:555)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:490)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:127)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:195)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:72)
Exception in thread "Thread-18" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
    at backup.StreamReader.run(StreamReader.java:86)
Exception in thread "Thread-17" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
    at backup.StreamReader.run(StreamReader.java:86)
Aug 2, 2012 12:08:44 PM backup.SSHExec run
SEVERE: null
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: socket closed
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.init(TransportImpl.java:164)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.onConnect(SSHClient.java:671)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:71)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:77)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:103)
    at backup.SSHExec.run(SSHExec.java:73)
    at backup.SSHExec.exec(SSHExec.java:42)
    at backup.BackupExec2.copyPrevBackup(BackupExec2.java:335)
    at backup.BackupExec2.run(BackupExec2.java:164)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.init(TransportImpl.java:158)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "Thread-23" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
    at backup.StreamReader.run(StreamReader.java:86)
Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
    at backup.StreamReader.run(StreamReader.java:86)
```

Is there a problem with starting mulitple SSHExec session in threads?  If not what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I have realized that I made an error in the notes above.  The SSHExec is an extension of the SSHClient that I put together.  That does not change the problem that I am having.

It seem that everything is fine up to when you execute the authPublickey method.  That method plus others seems to not allow multiple copies to be started at the same time.  So it looks like it is not possible to use SSHJ to create multiple connects at the same time at this point.

Comment: Have a look at the [overthere](https://github.com/xebialabs/overthere) library. We don't have a problem connecting to multiple (different) machines in different threads using ssh.